# R Take Updated Maximum

Tags: r, dplyr

Sample Data

```
data =data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 score=c(5,7,6,9,8,4,NA,11,3,7,NA,10),
                 WANT=c(5,7,7,9,9,9,NA,11,11,7,7,10))
```

Basically WANT should be equals to the maximum value of score at each row for each ID. As you can see it updates. This is my attempt but it does not handle the NA values.

```
data$WANT <- ave(data$score, data$id, FUN=!is.na(cummax))
```

Comment: @d.b - though this doesn't handle negative values. Might have to do an overwrite at the end to insert `NA` values if they are in the first position too. At the moment this replaces row 7's `NA` with `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ave(data$score, data$id, FUN = function(x){
    temp = cummax(replace(x, is.na(x), -Inf))
    temp[temp == -Inf] = NA
    temp
})
# [1]  5  7  7  9  9  9 NA 11 11  7  7 10
```